# Bootstrap "col" configuration with no number at xl

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

all,

I'm doing a bootstrap-made project where I have one row with five children:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">[content]</div>
      <div class="col">[content]</div>
      <div class="col">[content]</div>
      <div class="col">[content]</div>
      <div class="col">[content]</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

(The content itself is a Bootstrap card, if that is of any concern)

So I've got some of the flexible layout classes going on on those col divs:

```
      <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">[content]</div>
```

And that's fine at the smaller widths, it leads to wrapping, and I'm OK with that. But there comes a point where the screen is wide enough such that there's room for all five pieces of content. I just would like at that size for the content divs to act like they were just `class="col"`, so that they will share the one row and evenly divide up the space.

I tried `col-xl-auto` and that doesn't seem to cut it: the cards just reduce to their "natural" sizes and they don't fill the row nicely.

I thought I understood the concept of bootstrap's `row-cols-*` functionality, but I am getting awful results. I tried putting on the row `class="row row-cols-xl-5"` and on each content div `col-xl-1` and that didn't work: the row just limits itself to the space that was previously occupied by the first five of 12 columns, and then the cards squeeze into there. I had expected that `row-cols-*` took the same horizontal space that had before been divided into 12 columns and instead divided the same space into * columns, rather than just limiting the width of the row. Am I misunderstanding that?

Anyway, does anyone have an idea about what I'm trying to accomplish, that `col-xl-something` will give me the standard `col` action?

Comment: Have you tried just col-xl? I did a quick test on one of my bootstrap 5 sites and it seemed to work for me?

Comment: That was a forehead-slapping moment...but I just tried it and no. Here is what I have for the row: `row g-1`, and here is what I just tried for the cards: `col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl`. It seems like they have stuck at col-lg-4, and do not reorganize above that.

Comment: UPDATE: I poked at this for a while, and then decided to switch to flex instead. It still represents a trade-off: with Bootstrap grid, I get a more appropriate wrap (the wrapped cards don't expand) but a lesser single line (the non-wrapped cards do not expand to fill). With flex, I get a nice single line, but on wrap I get the cards stretching to fill. It's not too bad, if it's not just a one-card orphan. The best outcome to my eye would still be to get the grid working as I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### A few lessons

> I tried putting on the row class="row row-cols-xl-5" and on each content div col-xl-1 and that didn't work

Column classes are higher in hierarchy than row classes. So what you are doing here is forcing each column to be 1/12 (8.33%) in width with `.col-xl-1`, which **overrides** the `.row-cols-xl-5` column width of 20%.

Note that Bootstrap doesn't actually make each `row` 12 columns, it utilizes `width %` and `flex-` properties (`-grow`, `-shrink`, `-basis`) to size the columns. This is different than using CSS Grid where one would say a `div` should `span` multiple columns.

> `<div class="col col-12 ...">[content]</div>`

The class `.col` serves no purpose here after you also use `.col-12`. The class `.col` sets `flex-grow: 1;` on the column, which will be overridden by `.col-12` which sets `flex-grow: 0;` but adds `width: 100%`.

> I tried col-xl-auto and that doesn't seem to cut it

Using `-auto` will give the columns their natural (minimum) width. It sets `flex-grow: 0;` and `width: auto;` on the columns.

##### Solution

> does anyone have an idea about what I'm trying to accomplish, that
> col-xl-something will give me the standard col action?

**Remember** how column classes will override row classes? Well let's put that to use.

This will generate:

- by default full width columns: `.row-cols-1`;
- at `md` breakpoint two equal columns: `.row-cols-md-2`;
- at `lg` breakpoint three equal columns: `.row-cols-lg-3`;
- at `xl` breakpoint: `.col-xl` columns will have `flex-grow: 1;`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3">
     <div class="col-xl">[content]</div>
     <div class="col-xl">[content]</div>
     <div class="col-xl">[content]</div>
     <div class="col-xl">[content]</div>
     <div class="col-xl">[content]</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, you did not specify in your question what your ideal layout would be, nor did you add the cards. Therefore I cannot offer you any other solutions, but ask yourself this: do I need to specify the number of columns for my layout? And at what viewport width does the layout not behave how I want it to? Only then, add column numbers.

Because if you simply want [a free-flowing card layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/#card-layout), just use the layout you started your question with, perhaps only with stacked columns by default but start wrapping at `md` breakpoint:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md">[content]</div>
      <div class="col-md">[content]</div>
      <div class="col-md">[content]</div>
      <div class="col-md">[content]</div>
      <div class="col-md">[content]</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick! I knew I was overcomplicating things somehow. The outcome I wanted was the top row of cards always stretched end-to-end, with each card taking exactly 1/nth of the horizontal space...and cards that wrapped having the same width as the ones above, rather than either stretching to fill or making their own width. This worked! I didn't even have to put the col-xl bit...just col. That is, let the `row-cols-xx-#` handle how many columns there were, and inside that each card just act like a regular col. Golden! Thank you!